# AD users cannot publish anymore

Tags: publishing, security, azure-ad

We have users that login through AD and some users that don't (just plain Sitecore users).

After a deploy the AD users seems unable to publish. They can use the publish feature but the results is always 0 items published and nothing changes indeed. The Sitecore users don't seem to have the issue. We did patch the Publishing.CheckSecurity setting to true.

This settings was altered because we do want the security to be validated when publishing...

I assume this is related. How can we fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We validated that it is related by removing the patch - setting the Publish.CheckSecurity back to false - and confirming that the issue was gone.

But now our security isn't checked anymore during a publish so users could potentially publish items (descendants) they don't have rights to.

Sitecore confirmed this is a bug - the security check during a publish cannot determine the roles and security settings from an AD user and hence thinks the user has no rights to publish anything.
(bug reference number 477485)

A workaround is to assign the role(s) to the appropriate Azure AD users directly via the User Manager.